# login to site with curl-php not working when loggin into 2shared site

Tags: php, libcurl

I am Trying to login to 2shared with curl-php but for some reason it just returns me login page and does not set proper cookies in cookie file. Below is my code. Thanks for any help.

```
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$cookie = "cookie.txt";

$jsonp = 'jsonp'.time();

if (file_exists($cookie)) {
    unlink($cookie);
}

$post = array(
    "login" => $user,
    "password" => $pass,
    "callback" => $jsonp
);

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.2shared.com/login?callback=".$jsonp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.2shared.com/');       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

**EDIT:**

When I login via browser and watch traffic via HTTP analyzer i noticed after hitting login button it returns this data and redirect to loginRedirect object and i notice it set some cookies which does not appears while I am doing php-curl request:

```
{
    "ok":true,
    "rejectReason":"",
    "loginRedirect":"http://www.2shared.com/account/homeDoorway.jsp;jsessionid=3F253C7C641C7A8402D4AC9872C1CEAE.dc282?rand=0.8112776952920494",
    "loggedIn":"myemail@email.com",
    "needActivation":false
}
```

But when trying to login with curl-php above code it return me this data:

```
jsonp1339804887({
    "ok":true,
    "rejectReason":"",
    "loginRedirect":"http://www.2shared.com/login.jsp?sessionUnavailable=1",
    "loggedIn":"",
    "needActivation":false
})
```

Comment: Have you perused the 19 dozen hundred other `cURL login to some other site but can't` questions on SO?

Comment: Yes and actually I hv developed dozen as well but never came across such like above so asked here for help.

Comment: Let's switch positions metaphorically and I've asked this question and you're trying to figure it out. What is wrong exactly? What proved to work/not work? What was tried? What happens? Errors? Anything? This looks for all intents and purposes like 99% of the generic "my cURL stuff isn't working can you spot why?" questions. Mainly, because there is no detail except the code. Help us help you, give us the detail that matters about what's going on.

Comment: I have updated post with more information. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I reformatted it so it is easier for others to understand.

Comment: Also, by not using https (ssl/tls) in your request, you're sending your username and password plus all other information you're sending in the clear for anyone to see who can intercept it. Just a warning that you should switch to https for authentication if you can.

Comment: Ok thank you, And i am actually trying to login above site from last 3 days with no success, tried various methods but failed.

Comment: You might take a look at this tool's [README](http://grip.espace-win.org/doc/apps/plowshare/README), which if you search down the page for 2shared there's an entry showing how to use [`plowdown`/Plowshare](http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/) to get a file. That might offer you some clues if you look at the source.

Comment: For instance, this library file is all about 2shared: http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/source/browse/src/modules/2shared.sh

Comment: Thanks sir i actually read above code and its almost same as mine (OGIN_DATA='login=$USER&password=$PASSWORD&callback=jsonp') but still no success. I actually just noticed in my http analyzer there are some cookies with HtppOnly Flag which are not being saved in cookie file, here is hint message from HTTP analyzer ::  The HttpOnly flag was not set on the "day1host;hostid;JSESSIONID;df;sd;afu;afp;adu;adp;asl;chf;dirPwdVerified;premiumLogin;ulin;ADMIN_IDv2;WWW_JSESSIONID;searchAdmin;tblLoginLog;Login;Password;saveLogin;autoLogin;premiumLogin;ulin" cookie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always when doing web scraping, the key is to compare with a recorded session done manually with a browser (like with LiveHTTPHeaders or similar tools). Then make sure that your script is sending a request as similar as the recorded one as possible.

If you had done that, you would've seen that...

The login form on 2shared doesn't seem to use a multipart formpost, so your passing of $array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS is wrong. It should simply be a string in the form of "login=$name&password=$secret". This said, this may not be the only flaw in your approach.

Comment: I just noticed, I actually cant believe you are "Daniel Stenberg" :) Thanks sir, you are legend and I am big fan of your work :)....God bless you

Comment: Thank you for the kind words!

Answer (score 0):

This may be just a short in the dark, but it appears to me that you actually should look at the redirect and follow it. The error message does indicate that you're not actually within a functioning session on the server side – and the session identification is part of the address that you would have been redirected to but chose not to follow. `;jsessionid=3F253C7C641C7A8402D4AC9872C1CEAE.dc282` The latter part `?rand=0.8112776952920494` appears – to me! – to be a random number the system also wants to have sent back. I'll take this to be a trivial token mechanism to make sure that the request actually is fresh and not something like a script that tries to get in :-)

Also, are you certain that the callback mechanism you use (with time) does make so much sense?

Have you tried to get to the login page innocently, watching for the redirect to pop up and then start your other code from there?

Comment: Thank you for your reply but problem was i was sending post data as array instead string as mentioned by Daniel...all solved...Regards